# Gitlab Schedules API returns only first 25 schedules

Tags: bash, gitlab

I have about 200 pipeline schedules in my gitlab project so i wish to turn em active and inactive whenever i want wtih a single script. I wrote that

`for id in $(curl -X GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:<token>" "<project_url>" | jq '.[].id'); do curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:<token>" --form active="false" "<project_url>/$id"; done`

but the first curl request returns only like first 25 schedules so wish to know how to get all schedules using this API

Thanks in advance

Solved this way

`for i in $(eval echo "{1..<page_quantity>}"); do for id in $(curl -X GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:<token>" "<project_url>?per_page=100&page=$i" | jq '.[].id'); do curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:<token>" --form active="false" "<project_url>/$id"; done; done`

Comment: Don't have a gitlab account, but `<project_url>?per_page=100&page=2` to the the second page of 100 perhaps?

Comment: Docs say there should also be a link header returned with navigation links with the response; https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#pagination-link-header